# Is there any jquery simulators where I can practice usage of selectors

Tags: jquery, testing, css-selectors

I tried to search on net but I couldn't find any jquery simulators.
By simulator I mean a page where I can write jquery code and see what it's executing, what is selected, how jquery selectors work etc.

Is there anything similar on net?

Thanx
Marko

Comment: Use Firefox with Firebug and FireQuery extensions. Go to any site click jQuerify in firebug, and use jQuery in the console tab of firebug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) to be an excellent tool for this :)

Here's a base fiddle I use which has jQuery, jQuery UI and a jQuery UI theme/CSS already included:
http://jsfiddle.net/S8Lgp/

Here's a version with some simple content in it: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/fjPAN/

You can use fiddle to test any of the major javascript frameworks with any HTML and CSS you want, in answering questions here as well as personal and professional use...well, I have yet to find anything better, or that comes close really.

Answer (score 2):

Just to provide an alternative.  I really like [JSBin](http://jsbin.com)

Answer (score 1):

use firebug with firefox you can edit in  "realtime"

write script. styles etc... can't get any better than that :)

Comment: The same is true for Chrome, if you're working on a page and not a test case this is by far the way to go, a great way to quickly edit the real thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the new jQuery live editor which offers inbuilt sublime text editor inside with instant live previews.

[jQuery Live Editor](http://www.snoopcode.com/jquery/jquery-live-editor)

This is really an awesome way to see the instant live previews along with beautifully highlighted code in sublime text.